# How to use MakeExpression for single characters

Tags: front-end, customization, parsing

Here is code that I thought would make the front end parse `f` as `BigFunction`:

```
MakeExpression["f", StandardForm] := MakeExpression["BigFunction", StandardForm]
```

It works provided it is the only thing in the input:

```
f
(* BigFunction *)
```

But it doesn't work if it appears anywhere *inside* a larger expression:

```
f + 1
(* f + 1 *)    (* I want BigFunction + 1 *)

f[x]
(* f[x] *)     (* I want BigFunction[x] *)
```

How do I make single character expressions parse as longer names?

---

**Note**: Since I want the conversion to occur during parsing, I don't want to use `Set`:

```
f = BigFunction
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to your definition

```
MakeExpression["f", StandardForm] :=  MakeExpression["BigFunction", StandardForm]
```

you can use:

```
MakeExpression[RowBox[{x___, "f", y___}], StandardForm] := 
   MakeExpression[RowBox[{x, "BigFunction", y}], StandardForm]
```

and your examples will work. Add also:

```
MakeExpression[h_[x___, "f", y___], StandardForm] := 
 MakeExpression[h[x, "BigFunction", y], StandardForm]
```

and it should cover `***Box` cases:

[image]

Comment: It works.  But I'm worried the catch-all pattern might be quite inefficient for larger inputs.  Do you have any thoughts on this, or have any alternatives in mind?  Also, do you know if *Mathematica* uses the same catch-all pattern to parse `π` -> `Pi`?

Comment: @QuantumDot yep, noticed that inconvenience, I will try to figure it out ;) `$PreRead` would be a quick fix but it is not what should be done.

Comment: @QuantumDot is my edit enough?

Comment: @QuantumDot I've talked with J.Harris at WTC about that, it seems that symbols like Pi are handled in a special way so those three rules seem inevitable.

Comment: I couldn't get the third rule to work unless I use: `MakeExpression[RowBox[{h_, "[", RowBox[{x___, "f", y___}], "]"}], 
   StandardForm] := MakeExpression[RowBox[{h,   "[", RowBox[{x, "BigFunction", y}], "]"}], StandardForm]`.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: One other bizzare problem:  It doesn't work with blanks *e.g* `g[f_] := f` fails to match `f` on both sides because the box structure of `f_` is simply `"f_"`.  Very strange...; any ideas on making that part work?

Comment: Well... I guess `g[π_] := π` also fails to match on both sides, so I can't ask for too much.

Comment: @QuantumDot sorry, I was quite busy lately, will try to get back to this topic soon.

Comment: @QuantumDot about the third rule, it seems to be what I intendend to be, where does it fail for you? Don't know about the pattern case :/ seems to be an additional hardcoded exception in a parser. Won't work in general but if you are the only user you can go with: `g[\[Pi] : _] := \[Pi]`

Comment: The third rule doesn't work for `h[left, f, right]`.  It gets parsed to `BigFunction` only with the rule I suggested above.  Would you kindly check?

Comment: @QuantumDot you are right, it seem one should not make to narrow rules, that is a 'sequence' in `RowBox[{x___, "f", y___}]` can be converted to expression without the context. So yes, your note is on topic, maybe we should go even further and use `RowBox[{h___, RowBox[{x___, "f", y___}], k___}]` to handle or variations like `@@` etc.